# Drag-drop to Thunderbird works poorly with Wayland

Tags: nautilus, thunderbird, wayland

I am getting behavior where if I drag and drop an attachment (jpg, docx)  onto a Thunderbird compose window, often it does not get attached. As I am dragging, the window overlay that shows that it's going to be attached comes and goes as I move the mouse to different parts of the compose window. Not different *parts* or widgets of the window, but just randomly appears/disappears as I move the mouse around on the compose area. Often I have to try to drag and drop something three or five times in order to get it to attach. This is Ubuntu 21.10 Wayland. Is anybody else seeing behavior like this?

ETA: also the mouse cursor disappears from the compose window when I do successfully drag and drop in an attachment. It still functions normally (i.e., I can type), it's just not visible. If I save the email as a draft and then reopen it, the cursor comes back.